# Can a pelt of the beast cause the wearer to assume a form smaller or larger than normal?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items, monsters

The [*pelt of the beast*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/pelt-of-the-beast) (15,600; 8 lbs.), among other effects, says that

> The wearer may take the form of the animal from which the *pelt* came three times per day as if using *beast shape I*.

The spell [*beast shape I*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape) says that

> When you cast this spell, you can assume the form of any Small or Medium creature of the animal type.

Animals from which the *pelt* can come include, among others, the Diminutive [bat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/bat/bat), the Large [crocodile](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/crocodilians/crocodile/crocodile), the Tiny [rat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/rat/rat-common), the Large [shark](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/shark/shark), the Large [tiger](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/cat-great/tiger), and the [bear](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/bear), which *could be* Large. (I've provided these animal links as likely animals; *precise* animals aren't described by the item.)

**What happens when a creature uses *pelt of the beast* to assume the form of a creature that, because of that's creature's size, cannot normally be assumed using the spell *beast shape I*?**

Comment: Try to imagine all life as you know it stopping instantaneously and every molecule in your body exploding at the speed of light.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading it literally, it says "as if" but overrules specifically *what* you can change into. So that means that if you pick a Bat, you will become Diminutive and if you picked a Crocodile you become Large.

However, you still only gain the listed abilities up to the speeds mentioned, even if the animal has better, and there are no changes to your stats for picking an animal that isn't Small or Medium, so in those cases you'd be stuck with your own statistics.

(a DM *might* rule that you get the Small bonuses if the Animal is less then Small and the Medium bonuses if the Animal is larger than Medium, but that would be the DM's call. It would also be fair to say that the change in Space/Reach is enough of an advantage already.)